# Fail to connect database to Typescript ES module

Tags: typescript, typeorm, es6-modules

I'm trying to use TypeOrm library in order to connect to database from my Typescipt code. Whenever I use this library with CommonJs code, it works just fine. But when I try to setup a ESM project by running

```
npx typeorm init --name MyProject --database postgres --module esm
```

command and later try to connect to the database by running

```
npm start
```

it gives me following error:

```
npm start

> romacheck@0.0.1 start
> node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts

(node:12236) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Error [ERR_LOADER_CHAIN_INCOMPLETE]: "ts-node/esm 'resolve'" did not call the next hook in its chain and did not explicitly signal a short circuit. If this is intentional, include `shortCircuit: true` in the hook's return.
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:843:13)
    at async ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:7) {
  code: 'ERR_LOADER_CHAIN_INCOMPLETE'
}
```

How can I solve this error? Is there any other proved way to connect to database (mysql, postgres, anything) from ES module? Is there a way to make one file in the project of type module and another of type CommonJs and use the later in order to upload the data provided by the first one to database and read from the database?

I need the top-level await from the ES module. So if there is a way to make file CommonJs and still have access to top-level await, I'm open to it.

I tried changing the database (mysql to postgres). It doesn't help.